# MongoDB Sum Array With Objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have an aggregation that returns the following:

```
  [
    {driverId: 21312asd12, cars: 2, totalMiles: 30000, family: 4},
    {driverId: 55512a23a2, cars: 3, totalMiles: 55000, family: 2},
    ...
  ]
```

How would I go about running a summation of each data set on a groupId basis to return the following? Do I use an $unwind? Do another grouping?

For example I would like to return:

```
{ 
  totalDrivers: 2,
  totalCars: 5,
  totalMiles: 85000,
  totalFamily: 6
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just be referring to the documents in the output as an "array", therefore just add another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to the end of your pipeline:

```js
{ "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "totalDrivers": { "$sum": 1 },
    "totalCars": { "$sum": "$cars" },
    "totalMiles": { "$sum": "$totalMiles" },
    "totalFamily": { "$sum": "$family" }
}}
```

Where `null` is essentially just a blank grouping key that is not a field present in the document to group on. The result should be a single document (albeit in an array, depending on the API method call used or server version).

Or if you actually mean that each document has a field with an array like this, then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and process the group either per document or with a `null` as above:

```js
{ "$unwind": "$someArray" },
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "totalDrivers": { "$sum": 1 },
    "totalCars": { "$sum": "$someArray.cars" },
    "totalMiles": { "$sum": "$someArray.totalMiles" },
    "totalFamily": { "$sum": "$someArray.family" }
}}
```

At any rate, you should really post the code you are using when asking questions like this. It is very likely that your pipeline may not be as efficient to get to your end goal as you think, and if you posted that it both gives a clear picture of what you are doing as well as leaves it open for suggested improvement.

Comment: I actually figured it out using the first method you mentioned, but you beat me to posting the answer so I will up-vote your answer!